# why i am not getting the .csv file in my asp.net application using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

i am trying to get a .csv file on client machine by a click of a button by this code:

```
Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv"; ;
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=WBS.csv");
    Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
    string output = "WBSCode,Description,TerritoryCode,Amount" + "\n";
    Response.Write(output);
```

the problem is the code is executing but i am not getting a .csv file in my machine.. what is the problem ? i am doing this for the 1st time

Comment: Are you doing this from .ashx handler?

Comment: Yes you should. Basically the button should specify a url to the .ashx. The ashx will then have the code you pasted.

Comment: unless UpdatePanel is used, it should be possible to do this on button click as well

Comment: isn't there any other way but to do this?

Comment: yes i am using an `Update Panel` so i have to have a .ashx handler?

Comment: It is probably possible to do it from the aspx code-behind (although I am not 100% sure), but in my view isn't the best approach, since you are not really separating your logic into re-usable components. Also .ashx has better performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a generic handler (.ashx file), which will send the csv as response. Your button then simply needs to have a url to that .ashx. Below is the example of the handler with some of your code.

```
public class GetCsvFile : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=WBS.csv");
        context.Response.Write("WBSCode,Description,TerritoryCode,Amount\n");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i am able to solve it thanks guys but 1 more query after the file got downloaded i am still getting the update panel picture ... how can i solve this?

Comment: Hm.. Not sure about that one. Try to use a normal html link instead of a button (asp:Button), e.g. - `<a href='getcsvfile.ashx'>get file</a>`.